# Percentage height basing on 2 div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div inside another one

```
<div id="1">
    <div id="11">aaa</div>
    <div id="12"></div>
</div>
```

I don't know the height of #11 and #1 height is 100%;
How can i set 100% of #12, without going overflow?

```
#12 { height: calc(100% - ?); }
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't do it this way

Comment: so you want #12 to be the same height as #11, and #11's height depends on its content?

Comment: no, if #11 is 12px height (and i don't know how much tall it is), #12 should be calc(100% - 12px)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the height of id#1? This sounds like a job for flex-box to me. Here's an article on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I learned by playing around [here](http://flexiejs.com/playground/). I'm not sure if it's up to date with the newest syntax but it should help still.

Comment: If you go with flexbox, be aware of your audience.  Your users will need IE10+.

Answer (score 0):

Not-so-elegant, but how about some JavaScript that dynamically adjusts the height of your inner divs when a new element is added/removed? If children are never dynamically added/removed then you can do the calc once onload/ready.